# SharePoint 2013 - Search results web part - how to display page title instead of page filename

Tags: search, search-results, properties, tags, property

I'm trying to set up landing pages with a dynamic page list based off tags, I've gotten it to work correctly - how ever I can not for the life of me get the results to display with their correct page title - they only display with the page name.

It works fine for sub-sites of course using the SiteTitle field, but there is no PageTitle (of course).

What is the best way around this? I've done a fair bit of searching on the internet and have found some possible solutions (for example property mapping) but they are all using Central Administration which I do not have access to. My access is Collection Administrator via the site settings front end.

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance!

-Dan

Comment: Did you check the configuration of the Title managed property? Maybe it's mapped to the wrong crawled properties or maybe the order of mapped crawled properties was changed to make an item's name (FileLeafRef?) more important than it's Title.